# Why is dune refusing to download dependencies?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

I expected `dune` to automatically download dependencies when running `dune build`, but that doesn't happen.

I've tried multiple variants of this, and I tried with ocaml versions 4.14 and 5.0, and with different dune versions written in the `dune-project` file (although I didn't try to manually download specific `dune` versions, I wasn't sure that would happen automatically), my globally installed `dune` version is the latest, 3.10.

This specific set of instructions below was tried in an empty directory, and following the instructions of [dune's official documentation](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quick-start.html#building-a-hello-world-program-using-core-and-jane-street-ppxs).

```
~> echo '(lang dune 3.10)' > dune-project
~> echo '(executable
          (name hello_world)
          (libraries core)
          (preprocess (pps ppx_jane)))' > dune
~> echo 'open Core

         let () =
           Sexp.to_string_hum [%sexp ([3;4;5] : int list)]
           |> print_endline' > hello_world.ml'
~> dune build
File "dune", line 3, characters 12-16:
3 |  (libraries core)
                ^^^^
Error: Library "core" not found.
-> required by _build/default/hello_world.exe
-> required by alias all
-> required by alias default
File "dune", line 4, characters 18-26:
4 |  (preprocess (pps ppx_jane)))
                      ^^^^^^^^
Error: Library "ppx_jane" not found.
-> required by _build/default/hello_world.pp.ml
-> required by alias all
-> required by alias default
```

The error I get is always related to dependencies not ever being found. I tried copying other projects, running other tutorials with different sets of dependencies and whatnot, it's always the same error. I tried to manually meddle with an `.opam` file, but it looks like `dune` just ignores that and rewrites it.

Running a project without any dependencies works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Opam is the package manager for OCaml and its role is installing dependencies.

Dune on the other hand is a build system. The two have distinct roles.

Running `dune build` will give you errors about missing dependencies, but it should *also* update your project's opam file, allowing you to install the needed dependencies with `opam install . --deps-only`. Once this is done, `dune build` should succeed as long as the missing dependencies are the only source of errors.

Comment: I don't get it. All the documentation and tutorials I could find (including the one I linked above) say that you only need to do `dune build`, never `opam install`, and `dune build` doesn't work.

Comment: In other projects I did without any dependencies I also noticed that `dune build` **does** create or update the opam file (after it downloads the dependencies, I assume), but in my case it doesn't update or create the opam file. In fact it _empties_ an opam file if one already exists. I assume that is because of the errors.

So there is nothing to call `opam install` on.

Comment: @fiatjaf you need to add `(generate_opam_files true)

(package
 (name hello_world)
 (depends core ppx_jane))
` to your dune-project file to generate opam files. A example can be found here, https://github.com/anmonteiro/ocaml-h2/blob/master/dune-project

Comment: Thank you, that worked for generating the opam file, but the opam file is missing the dependencies. I thought they would be parsed directly from the `dune` file.