# How to include Z3 in Dune project?

Tags: ocaml, z3, opam, dune

I've been using `ocamlbuild` to build my projects, but OCaml has abandoned `ocamlbuild` so I wanted to dunify my projects. I'm trying to compile a project with the opam Z3 package. However, I'm encountering:

```
Error: Library "Z3" not found.
```

when I try to run `dune build`.

On `ocambuild` this was done via:

```
-package z3
```

I was reading the Dune documentation, but it's unclear what stanza I need to add to my dune files. The `libraries` and `package` stanzas do not do it. Do I perhaps need to write something in the `<project name>.opam` file? How does one link opam libraries to dune generally?

EDIT:
I believe it was an issue with switches. `ocamlbuild` appears to be able to find the binaries for `z3` using `ocamlfind`, whereas `dune` needs `z3` installed in the right place. For completeness, the `dune` file needs to be as follows:

```
(executable
 (name main)
 (libraries z3))
```

and `z3` needs to be installed on whichever switch you are running `dune` from. In my case, one of the switches did not have `z3` installed.

Comment: Can you show us your dune file?

Comment: I think you're running into the fact that dune is a build system, and spam is a package management system. If you don't have the Z3 library installed, and try to use dune to build a project that depends on it, you will get an error. Dune will not automatically download missing dependencies. Your instinct to look at your opam file is sound.

Comment: See a recent question on Stack Overflow: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77024393/why-is-dune-refusing-to-download-dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77024393/why-is-dune-refusing-to-download-dependencies)

Comment: @Chris thank you for your reply. I am aware Dune is a build system. I have Z3 installed via opam. I can run ocamlbuild with `-package z3`. My question is how to make Dune aware of the libraries installed via opam.

Comment: about the dune file. I'm new to dune, so I don't know which file to show. There are 2 files named dune in my repository, 1 file named dune-project. The one in `bin` has the `executable` stanza. The one in `lib` has the `library` stanza.

Comment: Does something like `(executable (name foo) (libraries z3))` not work for you?

Comment: yes, that's precisely what doesn't work. I get:
```
Error: Library "z3" not found.
Hint: try:
  dune external-lib-deps --missing @@default
```
but I don't understand this error message.

Comment: to add more details: running `opam list` I can see `z3  4.12.2-1  Z3 solver`, which `ocamlbuild` has no problem finding. I'm running an OCaml 4.10 switch,

Comment: I think I have solved it. It's probably a problem with switches. I have both 4.08 and 4.10 switches for opam. I think for whatever reason dune was being called from a switch that didn't have Z3, but ocamlbuild could use ocamlfind to find the Z3 binaries.